# LDAP authentification with group membership

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, openldap

I need to manage several linux hosts and I try to set a centralized authentication mechanism with OpenLDAP. 
So on the ldap server :

```
ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
 \_cn=test_group (groupOfNames),ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
    \_ member: uid=test_user,ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
 \_uid=test_user (posixAccount),ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
 \_uid=another_user (posixAccount),ou=User,dc=example,dc=com
```

On one linux client, I want to allow access only for members of the **test_group** group, so in /etc/ldap.conf :

```
base dc=example,dc=com
uri ldap://ldap_server_ip
ldap_version 3
rootbinddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
pam_filter objectclass=posixAccount
pam_login_attribute uid
pam_groupdn cn=test_group,ou=Group,dc=example,dc=com
pam_member_attribute member
```

But the **another_user** user can also log in! What did I do wrong? Thanks

Comment: Did you start slapd and try it?

Comment: Yes the auth works with LDAP+PAM

Comment: You need to update /etc/openldap/ldap.conf as well.

Comment: What do I have to modify in this file?

Comment: Same as what you have done in /etc/ldap.conf

Comment: Nothing change. Users not registered in the test_group group can still log in.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem comes from the automatic configuration in the /etc/pam.d directory. For example the common-account file with:

```
account [success=2 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]        pam_unix.so 
account [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so
```

need to be changed to:

```
account sufficient  pam_ldap.so
account required    pam_unix.so
```

All it's OK now.